# What's wrong with this code to un-camel-case a string?

Tags: delphi, string, set

Here is my attempt to solve the [About.com Delphi challenge to un-camel-case a string](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphichallengesexercises/qt/delphi-challenge-uncamelcase.htm).

```
unit challenge1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
   check = 65..90;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  var s1,s2 :string;
  int : integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  checks : set of check;
begin
  s1 := edit1.Text;
  for i := 1 to 20  do
  begin
    int  :=ord(s1[i]) ;
    if int in checks then
      insert('  ',s1,i-1);
  end;
  showmessage(s1); 
end;

end.
```

`check` is a set that contains capital letters so basically whenever a capital letter is encountered the insert function adds space before its encountered (inside the `s1` string), but my code does nothing. `ShowMessage` just shows text as it was entered in `Edit1`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that `check` is a set, but you haven't assigned any value to it yet, so its value is indeterminate. There are not the characters you expect in it, so the `in` test probably always fails. (Didn't the compiler warn you that you hadn't assigned anything `check` yet?)

You don't really want to define `check` as a subrange type. Rather, you should replace `check` with the built-in [`TSysCharSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TSysCharSet) type, which is a set of characters. Then assign `check` like this:

```
check := ['A'..'Z'];
```

Furthermore, rather than check the numeric value of the string with `int` and `Ord`, just use the `Char` values directly: `if s1[i] in check`. You'll also want to use the `Length` function so you process the entire string instead of assuming that the input will always be exactly 20 characters long. You'll also want to store the result into something other than `s1` since, as [Caldon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931265/whats-wrong-with-this-code-to-un-camel-case-a-string/2931347#2931347), you don't want to modify it at the same time that you're still reading more characters from it.

Comment: Why is it empty? Undefined as Uwe says makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

if you try your program on e.g. string "MyText", then in the first loop it correctly recognizes that "M" is capital, and so it enters one space before it... so the string is " MyText"... now in the next loop, i=2, and s1[i] is again "M" and so it inserts one space before it... and so on...

Answer (score 2):

`checks` is local to the method and never initialized. It may contain random data, but most probably not the data you expect (perhaps it it is an empty set). So the `IF`-condition will probably never become true.